# Simple "[]" conditional

Tags: r

So I have one data frame with multiple columns, a good chunk of those columns are dichotomous variables of whether each case belongs to a certain group, said columns are the result of running %in% to turn them into a logical test and then codded into 0s and 1s. I ended up with only one of those columns with 1 per row, now I want create a category based on whether the row has a 1 or not. Why's my code not working (or very slow, it just seems stuck).

```
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Energía==1]==1
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Industria==1]==2
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Materiales==1]==3
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Prod_frec==1]==4
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Salud==1]==5
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Telecom==1]==6
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Serv_fin==1]==7
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Serv_púb==1]==8
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Serv_NoB==1]==9
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Tics==1]==10
```

my data:

```
structure(list(CLAVE.EMISORA = c("AC", "ACCELSA", "ACTINVR", 
"AEROMEX", "AGRIEXP", "AGUA", "AHMSA", "ALEATIC", "ALFA", "ALPEK", 
"ALSEA", "AMX", "ANB", "ARA", "ARISTOS", "ASUR", "AUTLAN", "AXTEL", 
"AZTECA", "BACHOCO", "BAFAR", "BBAJIO", "BBVA", "BEVIDES", "BIMBO", 
"BOLSA", "BSMX", "CABLE", "CADU", "CEMEX", "CERAMIC", "CHDRAUI", 
"CIDMEGA", "CIE", "CMOCTEZ", "CMR", "COLLADO", "CONVER", "CREAL", 
"CUERVO", "CULTIBA", "CYDSASA", "DINE", "EDOARDO", "ELEKTRA", 
"ELEMENT", "FEMSA", "FINAMEX", "FINDEP", "FRAGUA", "FRES", "GAP", 
"GAV", "GBM", "GCARSO", "GCC", "GENSEG", "GENTERA", "GEO", "GFAMSA", 
"GFINBUR", "GFMULTI", "GFNORTE", "GICSA", "GIGANTE", "GISSA", 
"GMD", "GMEXICO", "GMXT", "GNP", "GOMO", "GPH", "GPROFUT", "GRUMA", 
"GSANBOR", "HCITY", "HERDEZ", "HIMEXSA", "HOMEX", "HOTEL", "IASASA", 
"ICA", "ICH", "IDEAL", "IENOVA", "INGEAL", "INVEX", "JAVER", 
"KIMBER", "KOF", "KUO", "LAB", "LACOMER", "LALA", "LAMOSA", "LASEG", 
"LIVEPOL", "MAXCOM", "MEDICA", "MEGA", "MFRISCO", "MINSA", "MONEX", 
"NEMAK", "NMK", "OMA", "ORBIA", "PAPPEL", "PASA", "PE&OLES", 
"PINFRA", "PLANI", "POCHTEC", "POSADAS", "PROCORP", "PV", "Q", 
"QBINDUS", "QUMMA", "R", "RCENTRO", "RLH", "SAN", "SARE", "SAVIA", 
"SIMEC", "SITES", "SORIANA", "SPORT", "TEAK", "TEKCHEM", "TLEVISA", 
"TMM", "TRAXION", "TS", "UNIFIN", "URBI", "VALUEGF", "VASCONI", 
"VESTA", "VINTE", "VISTA", "VITRO", "VOLAR", "WALMEX"), RAZON.SOCIAL = c("ARCA CONTINENTAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ACCEL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CORPORACION ACTINVER, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO AEROMÉXICO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "AGRO INDUSTRIAL EXPORTADORA, S.A. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO ROTOPLAS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "ALTOS HORNOS DE MEXICO, S.A. DE C.V.", 
"ALEATICA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "ALFA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "ALPEK, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ALSEA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "AMERICA MOVIL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "ANHEUSER-BUSCH INBEV SA/NV", 
"CONSORCIO ARA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CONSORCIO ARISTOS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO AEROPORTUARIO DEL SURESTE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "COMPAÑIA MINERA AUTLAN, S.A.B. DE C. V.", 
"AXTEL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "TV AZTECA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INDUSTRIAS BACHOCO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO BAFAR, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "BANCO DEL BAJÍO, S.A., INSTITUCIÓN DE BANCA MÚLTIPLE", 
"BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA, S.A.", "FARMACIAS BENAVIDES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO BIMBO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "BOLSA MEXICANA DE VALORES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"BANCO SANTANDER MEXICO, S.A., INSTITUCION DE BANCA MULTIPLE, GRUPO FINANCIERO SANTANDER", 
"EMPRESAS CABLEVISION, S.A. DE C.V.", "CORPOVAEL S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CEMEX, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INTERNACIONAL DE CERAMICA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO COMERCIAL CHEDRAUI, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CORPORACION INTERAMERICANA DE ENTRETENIMIENTO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CORPORACION MOCTEZUMA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CMR, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"G COLLADO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CONVERTIDORA INDUSTRIAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CREDITO REAL, S.A.B. DE C.V., SOFOM, E.R.", "BECLE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ORGANIZACIÓN CULTIBA, S.A.B. DE CV", "CYDSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"DINE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "EDOARDOS MARTIN, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO ELEKTRA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ELEMENTIA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "FOMENTO ECONÓMICO MEXICANO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CASA DE BOLSA FINAMEX, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "FINANCIERA INDEPENDENCIA, S.A.B. DE C.V. SOFOM, E.N.R.", 
"CORPORATIVO FRAGUA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "FRESNILLO PLC", "GRUPO AEROPORTUARIO DEL PACIFICO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ACOSTA VERDE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CORPORATIVO GBM, S.A.B. DE C. V.", 
"GRUPO CARSO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO CEMENTOS DE CHIHUAHUA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GENERAL DE SEGUROS, S.A.B.", "GENTERA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CORPORACION GEO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO FAMSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO FINANCIERO INBURSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO FINANCIERO MULTIVA S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO FINANCIERO BANORTE, S.A.B DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO GICSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO GIGANTE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO INDUSTRIAL SALTILLO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO MEXICANO DE DESARROLLO, S.A.B.", 
"GRUPO MEXICO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GMÉXICO TRANSPORTES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO NACIONAL PROVINCIAL, S.A.B.", "GRUPO COMERCIAL GOMO, S.A. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO PALACIO DE HIERRO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO PROFUTURO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUMA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO SANBORNS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "HOTELES CITY EXPRESS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO HERDEZ, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "HIMEXSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "DESARROLLADORA HOMEX, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO HOTELERO SANTA FE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INDUSTRIA AUTOMOTRIZ, S.A. DE C.V.", 
"EMPRESAS ICA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INDUSTRIAS CH, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"IMPULSORA DEL DESARROLLO Y EL EMPLEO EN AMERICA LATINA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"INFRAESTRUCTURA ENERGETICA NOVA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INGEAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"INVEX CONTROLADORA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "SERVICIOS CORPORATIVOS JAVER, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"KIMBERLY - CLARK DE MEXICO S.A.B. DE C.V.", "COCA-COLA FEMSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO KUO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GENOMMA LAB INTERNACIONAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"LA COMER S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO LALA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO LAMOSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"LA LATINOAMERICANA SEGUROS, S.A.", "EL PUERTO DE LIVERPOOL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"MAXCOM TELECOMUNICACIONES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "MEDICA SUR, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"MEGACABLE HOLDINGS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "MINERA FRISCO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO MINSA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "MONEX, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "NEMAK, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"CONTROLADORA NEMAK, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO AEROPORTUARIO DEL CENTRO NORTE, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ORBIA ADVANCE CORPORATION, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "BIO PAPPEL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"PROMOTORA AMBIENTAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "INDUSTRIAS PEÑOLES, S. A.B. DE C. V.", 
"PROMOTORA Y OPERADORA DE INFRAESTRUCTURA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "PLANIGRUPO LATAM, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"GRUPO POCHTECA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO POSADAS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"PROCORP, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "PEÑA VERDE S.A.B.", "QUÁLITAS CONTROLADORA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"Q.B. INDUSTRIAS, S.A. DE C.V.", "GRUPO QUMMA, S.A. DE C.V.", 
"REGIONAL, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO RADIO CENTRO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"RLH PROPERTIES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "BANCO SANTANDER, S.A.", "SARE HOLDING, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"SAVIA, S.A. DE C.V.", "GRUPO SIMEC, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "TELESITES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"ORGANIZACION SORIANA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO SPORTS WORLD, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"PROTEAK UNO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "TEKCHEM, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO TELEVISA, S.A.B.", 
"GRUPO TMM, S.A.", "GRUPO TRAXIÓN S.A.B DE C.V.", "TENARIS S.A.", 
"UNIFIN FINANCIERA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "URBI DESARROLLOS URBANOS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"VALUE GRUPO FINANCIERO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "GRUPO VASCONIA S.A.B.", 
"CORPORACIÓN INMOBILIARIA VESTA, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "VINTE VIVIENDAS INTEGRALES, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"VISTA OIL & GAS, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "VITRO, S.A.B. DE C.V.", "CONTROLADORA VUELA COMPAÑÍA DE AVIACIÓN, S.A.B. DE C.V.", 
"WAL - MART DE MEXICO, S.A.B. DE C.V."), SECTOR = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 58L, 59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 
83L, 84L, 1L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 
96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 
107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 
118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 1L, 143L, 144L, 145L), Energía = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Industria = c(0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L
), Materiales = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), Prod_frec = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Salud = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    Telecom = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Serv_fin = c(0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Serv_púb = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Serv_NoB = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Tics = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, -145L), class = "data.frame")
```

[(link to csv dataset)](https://tmpfiles.org/dl/12576/mydata.csv)

Comment: We can't say without an example of your dataset or more information.

Comment: I added an online link, sorry if its not clear enough.

Comment: I've embedded the dataset, so that it is copy-pastable. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you're trying to do. From your code it seems like you're trying to overwrite the value in `SECTOR`, with the ones indicated by the different sector columns (A guess based on their names).

Basically the problem here is that you are not performing any assignment. For example

```
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Energía == 1] == 1
```

states: "Subset sector where `mdf$Energía == 1` and check the condition that the value is equal to 1.". This is how `==`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `!=`, `%in%` works. For assignment you use single equals `=` or the assignment operator `<-` (latter is recommended standard in R for pragmatic reasons). So the above would be replaced with

```
mdf$SECTOR[mdf$Energía == 1] <- 1
```

We could actually do this a bit simpler however. because you have some columns each with a value of 0 or 1, with no row having multiple (`unique(rowSums(mdf[, -c(1:3)]))` is of length 1) we can "abuse" a few different methods for removing a few lines of code. First of all we could multiple each column by 1 through 10 and just sum across rows using `mdf$SECTOR <- rowSums(sweep(mdf[, -(1:3)], 1, 1:10, '*'))`. Alternatively we could use `which` to find the position of the `1`'s. `mdf$SECTOR <- apply(mdf[, -(1:3)], 1, function(x)which(x == 1))`

Your method works out fine, so the alternatives are just for compactness and to get familiar with the R syntax.